# Need recommendation for Audio/video player libraries in java

Tags: java, user-interface, audio, video, video-player

I am working on a project where I need to create a Video/audio player in java that will allow a user to select a file they want to play and it to play that file. In the future, I am going to get the program to print the conversation of the audio/video file in real time, So i need to some how to create a video/audio player which has a elapsed time which I can be extract for the other component of the software.

I wondered if anyone could suggest some libraries for me to use or give me any advice they think could help me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "print the conversation" but if the issue is knowing how far into the playback stream you are (i.e., elapsed time) then any media player I've diddled with has the ability to establish a listener that gets periodic update events. If your target environment is Android then you can simply use the android.media.MediaPlayer. I've had good results with it. I can't, however, give you a recommendation for a non-Android Java environment.

Also you need to be aware that there some video formats (e.g. Quicktime) may not be supportable with a given player.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look on [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/). Also some alternatives to JMF were covered in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework#Alternatives).